# how to revert make install and use make altinstall

Tags: python-2.7, centos, python-3.4

i had followed this [tutorial](http://www.shayanderson.com/linux/install-python-3-on-centos-6-server.htm) in other to overwrite python2.7 with `python 3.4.4` and it worked very nice. Only one thing was wrong. typing `python`, still goes to `python2.7` and `python3` goes to `python3.4.4`. so from what i learnt is that

> > > It is critical that you use make altinstall when you install your custom version of Python. If you use the normal make install you will end up with two different versions of Python in the filesystem both named python. This can lead to problems that are very hard to diagnose.

Please help me revert this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

went through this blog [Install Python on Linux (Centos)](http://uobis.com/blog/install-python-linux-centos/).
I had to re-run `make altinstall` with `sudo` command of course. I tried this after that

```
`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.4 /usr/local/bin/python`.
```

which have me

```
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/python': File exists
```

I had to delete the path `/usr/local/bin/python`.
and then tried again.
problem solved